# Dynamically select a function to call without intermediate variables

Tags: rust

I'm trying to select a function to call depending on a condition. I want to store that function in a variable so that I can call it again later without carrying the condition around. Here's a working minimal example:

```
fn foo() {
    println! ("Foo");
}
fn bar() {
    println! ("Bar");
}

fn main() {
    let selector = 0;

    let foo: &Fn() = &foo;
    let bar: &Fn() = &bar;
    let test = match selector {
        0 => foo,
        _ => bar
    };
    test();
}
```

My question is: is it possible to get rid of the intermediate variables? I've tried simply removing them:

```
fn foo() {
    println! ("Foo");
}
fn bar() {
    println! ("Bar");
}

fn main() {
    let selector = 0;

    let test = match selector {
        0 => &foo as &Fn(),
        _ => &bar as &Fn()
    };
    test();
}
```

but then the borrow checker complains that the borrowed values are only valid until the end of the match (btw, why? the functions are `'static` anyway so should be valid to the end of times). I've also tried making the `'static` lifetime explicit by using `&foo as &'static Fn()` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works, if you only need to work with static functions and not closures:

```
fn foo() {
    println!("Foo");
}

fn bar() {
    println!("Bar");
}

fn main() {
    let selector = 0;

    let test: fn() = match selector {
        0 => foo,
        _ => bar
    };

    test();
}
```

(try on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02d23cb4ee5ab08f38df&version=stable))

Here I've used function type instead of function trait.

The reason that the borrowed trait object doesn't work is probably the following. Any trait object is a fat pointer which consists of a pointer to some value and a pointer to a virtual table. When the trait object is created out of a closure, everything is clear - the value would be represented by the closure itself (internally being an instance of a structure containing all captured variables) and the virtual table would contain a pointer to the implementation of the corresponding `Fn*()` trait generated by the compiler whose body would be the closure body.

With functions, however, things are not so clear. There are no value to create a trait object from because the function itself should correspond to the implementation of `Fn()` trait. Therefore, rustc probably generates an empty structure and implements `Fn()` for it, and this implementation calls the static function directly (not actual Rust, but something close):

```
struct SomeGeneratedStructFoo;

impl Fn<()> for SomeGeneratedStructFoo {
    type Output = ();
    fn call(&self, args: ()) -> () {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Therefore, when a trait object is created out of `fn foo()`, a reference is taken in fact to a temporary value of type `SomeGeneratedStructFoo`. However, this value is created inside the match, and only a reference to it is returned from the match, thus this value does not live long enough, and that's what the error is about.

Answer (score 2):

`fn()` is a function pointer type. It's **already** a pointer type. You can check this with `std::mem::size_of::<fn()>()`. It is not a zero-sized type.

When you do `&foo`, you take a pointer to a stack allocated pointer. This inner pointer does not survive very long, causing the error.

You can cast these to the generic `fn()` type as suggested. I would be interested in knowing why you can't cast `fn()` to `&Fn()`, though.